# Nested forms in Ruby with checkboxes and many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, strong-parameters

I am new to ruby and having a trouble in following scenario. I am trying to build a relationship between bill and items. In my case, I want to generate a bill at run time like when user clicks on create new bill, he is directed to a route like http://localhost:3000/bills/new and then he has a list of items from which he has to choose by checking the checkboxes and adding the quantity. I have 3 tables, Items, Bills, BillItems. They have following fields in them:

```
    create_table "bill_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "bill_id"
    t.integer "item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "quantity"
  end

  create_table "bills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

    create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.float "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
  end
```

I have my models created like this:

Bill.rb

```
 class Bill < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :bill_items
        has_many :items, through: :bill_items
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_items, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
    end
```

Item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    
    has_many :bill_items
    has_many :bills, through: :bill_items

end
```

BillItem.rb

```
class BillItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bill
    belongs_to :item
    
end
```

I have my form like:

```
<%= form_for @bill do |f| %>
 <% if @allItems %>

     <% @allItems.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
         <tr class="table-success" scope="col-8">
        <%= f.fields_for :bill_items do |s| %>
            <td class="text-secondary"><%= item.category.name %></td>
            <%= s.hidden_field :name, value: item.name %>
            <td class="text-primary"><%= s.label item.name %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "item_ids[]", item.id, false, class: 'selectable' %> </td> 
            <td><%= s.number_field(:quantity, in: 1.0..100.0, step: 1) %></td>
            <td><%= s.label  :price, item.price %></td>
           
        <% end %>
        </tr>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
    <%= f.submit "Create Order with Selected items", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then I have my controller setup like this:

```
def new
    @bill = Bill.new
    @bill_items = @bill.bill_items.build
    
end

def create 
    byebug
    @bill = Bill.new(bill_params)
    @bill.save
    redirect_to new_bill_path

end

private 
    def bill_params
         params.require(:bill).permit(bill_items_attributes: [:quantity, :item_ids])
    end
```

When I run my code and send data to form and check params via byebug it shows me following params, while i selected two items, of ids 1 and 4:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"hVnrTkWxWwuXqS4tb01INVkNwRaFooVERKe2L8YkXykyPqImKCVRrvqjhK8sA0Q26nsOS+dSNdLvIOPTfis8nQ==", "bill"=>{"bill_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"sheer", "quantity"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"burger", "quantity"=>""}, "2"=>{"name"=>"custurs", "quantity"=>""}, "3"=>{"name"=>"sib", "quantity"=>"4"}}}, "item_ids"=>["1", "4"], "commit"=>"Create Order with Selected items", "controller"=>"bills", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Then I click submit and it only saves bill in the db and gives me error

```
Unpermitted parameter: :name
Unpermitted parameter: :name
Unpermitted parameter: :name
Unpermitted parameter: :name`
```

I have tried many techniques and couldn't find a solution. It will be very helpful if someone can help me with this. Even if I need to redesign my logic then do help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "item_ids[]", item.id, false, class: 'selectable' %> </td>
```

has to be

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "bill[item_ids[]]", item.id, false, class: 'selectable' %> </td>
```

Comment: please let me know any other changes that are needed to be done in my controller params or modal as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem: There is a mismatch in nested attributes naming

Bill model is accepting nested attributes for `:items` 
On Controller you have specified `:bill_items_attributes` and
Form generating fields for bill_items -
`f.fields_for :bill_items`

Solution: make it consistent

On Bill model -

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`

On Bill Controller -

`permit(items_attributes:`

On form new.html.erb -

`f.fields_for :items`

However this will create another problem for items_id, which I am not sure what are trying to achieve there.

Answer (score 0):

You were getting those errors because you had hidden_field `:name` in form which is not required while submitting form. I removed that. However there was an issue with strong parameters and checkbox naming. I corrected strong params and kept checkbox naming descriptive so that you can see how form will generates it.

Try this code. I was able to create records with this code.

`bills_controller.rb`

```
private 
    def bill_params
         params.require(:bill).permit(bill_items_attributes: [:quantity, :item_id])
    end
```

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @bill do |f| %>
    <% if @allItems %>
        <% @allItems.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :bill_items do |s| %>
                <tr class="table-success" scope="col-8">
                    <td class="text-primary"><%= s.label item.name %></td>
                    <td><%= check_box_tag "bill[bill_items_attributes][#{index}][item_id]", item.id, false, class: 'selectable' %> </td> 
                    <td><%= s.number_field(:quantity, in: 1.0..100.0, step: 1) %></td>
                    <td><%= s.label  :price, item.price %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
   
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
        <%= f.submit "Create Order with Selected items", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```